# Python error expected str instance, set found

Tags: python

I'm trying to return video title and description from a youtube url.
I get this error after submitting a youtube url,  **TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, set found** for this line `s = '<br>'.join(videos)` , what did i do wrong and what does this mean?

```
@app.route("/add_video/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_video():
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or request.form.get('next')
    s = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form.get('youtube'):
        youtube = request.form.get('youtube')

        data = get_video_info(youtube)

        videos = []
        title = {data['title']}
        description = {data['description']}

        videos.append(title)
        videos.append(description)
        s = '<br>'.join(videos) 

    return render_template('add_video.html', next_url=next_url, video_info=s)
```

Comment: in which line you are having this issue?

Comment: `s = '<br>'.join(videos)`

Comment: Why did you put braces in `title = {data['title']}` and `description = {data['description']}`?

Comment: @user892134 why are you putting `data['title']` in set `{}`. simply doing `videos = data['title']` will work.

Comment: you are trying to join a list of sets? videos is appending `{data['title']}`, those entries are sets. Putting them in braces makes each a set but join only works on strings. what is `data['title']`?

Answer (score 0):

Note here:

```
    videos = []
    title = {data['title']}
    description = {data['description']}
    videos.append(title)
    videos.append(description)
```

1. You created a list of videos.
2. You created a set with the value data['title']
3. You created a set with the value data['description']
4. You then appended the set of title and description from (2) and (3) into the list of videos created at (1)

Notice that videos is now a list of dicts.

Finally you did

```
s = '<br>'.join(videos)
```

which tries to join a string with video (a list of dicts) thus **expected str instance, set found**